# How to identify Open Mic Issue in Google Assistant App?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, assistant

**Google Home Assistant APP** - I have created a google assistant app and submitted for review.
The submitted app was rejected stating the MIC is open in few of the Test cases and it should be closed in appropriate time.

I am no idea how to make the Mic Closed.

**What have I done?**

When there is a question from the user, my assistant app will answer the question and say thanks.
When a user asks other question it will answer, it will ask any other question and End the conversation.

In Dialogflow in Google Active console, I have this setup to make MIC close after the conversation.

[image]

**What do I suppose to do?**

I am ending the conversation when I don't listen to any input from the user, how to explicitly close the Mic from the listening mode.

Is there any specific option to close the MIC?

> **Error Response from Google Review Team:** During our testing, we found that your app would sometimes leave the mic open for the user
>   without any prompt. Make sure that your app always says something
>   before leaving the mic open for the user, so that the user knows what
>   they can say. This is particularly important when your app is first
>   triggered.